# How do i put google ads on my websearch (no text) application ?

Tags: web-applications, ads, google-ads-api

How do I put Google adds on my web application?

Services like `AdMob`, `AdSense` aren't supporting it. My web app is a normal HTML, jQuery web search application (no text).

AdMob`is only available for Android/iOS/Windows apps, whereas`AdSense` does not accept my web app URL, which is provided to me by Amazon.

Answer (score 1):

AdSense is the way to go here - as you mentioned, AdMob is designed for native apps, not web pages.

Are you going to eventually put the web app behind a domain name?  If so it could be worth submitting that domain now, although the page will be spidered when you sign up to AdSense and if they don't like it (e.g. if its just a holding page with no content) then it might get rejected for AdSense.